# Can't manage plugins anymore

Tags: plugins

I'm using Wordpress version 4.8.4. In a while, I've experienced some issues in the plugin management panel: I can't manage them at all, no enable/disable, it's impossible to remove or install them.

I can only view a plugin that I've installed named "Admin renamer extended". I've tried updating active_plugins field in wp_options to '', and it didn't work. I've also tried to rename that plugin folder, and if I do that, I can't see the plugin field on admin panel at all.

What can be wrong? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Try opening up the wp-config.php in a text editor and changeing the line that says `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );` to [`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and add `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` below it. Then navigate to the plugins management page and try to do whatever you are having trouble with. You should see any PHP errors that are occurring print to the screen as well as written to `wp-content/debug.log`. That may help narrow down your issue or atleast give you something to paste into here.

Comment: I tried what you told me. The "error" is a Notice, regarding "has_cap" who has been called with a deprecated argument from version 2.0.0 then it says things about user levels from themes and plugins and then I should use roles and capabilities. row 4024 on ../wp-includes/functions.php